# Extracting data from API (JSON format) doesn't save data outside of function call

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, swift3

I am trying to get an array of temperatures in a given time period from an API in JSON format. I was able to retrieve the array through a completion handler but I can't save it to another variable outside the function call (one that uses completion handler). Here is my code. Please see the commented area.

```
class WeatherGetter {

    func getWeather(_ zip: String, startdate: String, enddate: String, completion: @escaping (([[Double]]) -> Void)) {
        // This is a pretty simple networking task, so the shared session will do.
        let session = URLSession.shared

        let string = "api address"

        let url = URL(string: string)
        var weatherRequestURL = URLRequest(url:url! as URL)
        weatherRequestURL.httpMethod = "GET"


        // The data task retrieves the data.
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: weatherRequestURL) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                // Case 1: Error
                // We got some kind of error while trying to get data from the server.
                print("Error:\n\(error)")
            }
            else {
                // Case 2: Success
                // We got a response from the server!
                do {
                    var temps = [Double]()
                    var winds = [Double]()
                    let weather = try JSON(data: data!)
                    let conditions1 = weather["data"]
                    let conditions2 = conditions1["weather"]
                    let count = conditions2.count
                    for i in 0...count-1 {
                        let conditions3 = conditions2[i]
                        let conditions4 = conditions3["hourly"]
                        let count2 = conditions4.count
                        for j in 0...count2-1 {
                            let conditions5 = conditions4[j]
                            let tempF = conditions5["tempF"].doubleValue
                            let windspeed = conditions5["windspeedKmph"].doubleValue
                            temps.append(tempF)
                            winds.append(windspeed)
                        }
                    }
                    completion([temps, winds])
                }
                catch let jsonError as NSError {
                    // An error occurred while trying to convert the data into a Swift dictionary.
                    print("JSON error description: \(jsonError.description)")
                }
            }
        }
        // The data task is set up...launch it!
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}


I am calling this method from my view controller class. Here is the code. 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let weather = WeatherGetter()
        weather.getWeather("13323", startdate: "2016-10-01", enddate: "2017-04-30") { (weatherhandler: [[Double]]) in
            //It prints out the correct array here
            print(weatherhandler[0])
            weatherData = weatherhandler[0]
        }
        //Here it prints out an empty array
        print(weatherData)

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that API takes some time to return the data, when the data is return the "Completion Listener" is called and it goes inside the "getWeather" method implementation, where it prints the data of array. But when your outside print method is called the API hasn't returned the data yet. So it shows empty array. If you will try to print the data form "weatherData" object after sometime it will work.

The best way I can suggest you is to update your UI with the data inside the "getWeather" method implementation like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let weather = WeatherGetter()
    weather.getWeather("13323", startdate: "2016-10-01", enddate: "2017-04-30") { (weatherhandler: [[Double]]) in
        //It prints out the correct array here
        print(weatherhandler[0])
        weatherData = weatherhandler[0]

       // Update your UI here.

    }
    //Here it prints out an empty array
    print(weatherData)

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by update your UI? I am sorry. I am new to iOS programming.

Comment: Update UI means if you want to setting the data t your views. If you are using the data to show on some Labels then set the text, but if you are setting the data to a Tablview then call:

yourTableView.reloadData()

Comment: Oh I see. That helps a lot. I am basically just trying to take the array thats been returned by the completion handler and save it to a global variable which I can later use in the other part of my code. How do you suggest I achieve that?

Comment: It's already saved in your weatherData object. It just taking some time. When you will go to anyother controller and will access that object. I'll be having your data.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an error, when your `controller` get loaded the array is still empty because your `getWeather` is still doing its thing (meaning accessing the api, decode the json) when it finishes the `callback` will have `data` to return to your controller.

For example if you were using a tableView, you will have `reloadData()` to refresh the UI, after you assign data to `weatherData`

Or you could place a `property Observer` as you declaring your `weatherData` property.

```
 var weatherData:[Double]? = nil {
     didSet {
        guard let data = weatherData else {  return }
       // now you could do soemthing with the data, to populate your UI 
   }
}
```

now after the data is assigned to `wheaterData`, `didSet` will be called.

Hope that helps, and also place your jsonParsing logic into a `struct :)

Comment: I can print the array inside this declaration but still can't assign it to a global variable. I am sorry. I am new to this.